# Xcode Undefined symbols, Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile-development

I have ionic project with the following details:

- ionic v4.12.0
- cordova v12.0.0
- Jnode v14.20.0
- Cordova IOS v6.1.0
- Xcode v15.0
- Deployment target 11.0

All my code work perfect untill I upgrade xcode to v15.0 and start use mac studio

**What I did after upgrade xcode:**

- rm ios platfrom
- add ios platform
- rm node_modules and package-lock
- npm install
- Change Deployment target to 12.0 in config.xml and podfile

**config.xml**

```
<preference name="deployment-target" value="12.0" />
```

**podfile**

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'projectname' do
    pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '5.5.0'
    pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '5.5.0'
    pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '5.5.0'
    pod 'FirebaseMessaging', '~> 2.0.0'
    pod 'GoogleSignIn', '5.0.2'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
     target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.0'
     end
    end
   end
```

Then I'm ready to build ios platform I used commaned

```
ionic cordova build ios
```

Got error

```
warning: Run script build phase 'Copy www directory' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'projectname' from project 'projectname')
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/ABC/projectname/platforms/ios/build/emulator/projectname.app/projectname normal (in target 'projectname' from project 'projectname')
(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
```

**What I try:**

- Install cocoapods last version
- Update pod
- reinstall ios platform
- Run in xcode got the following error
- increace ionic version to v5

```
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please help and thank you in advance.